# Passing values from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know why my code is not working, I am trying to send the coordinates from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX and I am able to pull values from JavaScript to textbox but values are not passed to PHP. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({url:"samepage3.php",type:"POST",async:false,
   data:{getlat:$("#getlat").val(),getlon:$("#getlon").val()}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<input type="text" id="getlat" name="getlat" /> 
<input type="text" id="getlon" name="getlon" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST["getlat"]))
{
    $lat = $_POST["getlat"];
    echo $lat;
}
if(isset($_POST["getlon"]))
{
    $lon = $_POST["getlon"];
    echo $lon;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 1:

**I am running this code in file samepage3.php and I need the action to be happened on the same page without reloading the page**

Comment: Try  `data:{'getlat':$("#getlat").val(),'getlon':$("#getlon").val()`

Comment: PHP will only execute on page load.

Comment: No difference, still working in the same way as before

Comment: @BernardoLima - yeah, how can I make JS load before PHP?

Comment: Why not create a new php page, post to that, and then retrieve the response?

Comment: Your PHP needs to be on a separate page.

Comment: If you debug the requests made from this page, I believe the last thing it will do will be the POST, can't tell if you can manipulate that order.

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute the PHP script on the samepage3.php, **after** the page is fully loaded. I suggest to separate the page, and create the response using AJAX. Something like this.

File index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                }

            }
            function showPosition(position) {
                document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
            }

            function fireAjax(){
                $.ajax({url:"response.php",type:"POST",async:false,
                    data:{getlat:$("#getlat").val(),getlon:$("#getlon").val()},
                    success: function (response){
                        $('#response').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getLocation()">
        <input type="text" id="getlat" name="getlat" /> 
        <input type="text" id="getlon" name="getlon" />

        <button onclick="fireAjax()" >Send</button>

        <div id="response">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

File response.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["getlat"]))
{
    $lat = $_POST["getlat"];
    echo 'Latitude: ', $lat, '<br/>';
}
if (isset($_POST["getlon"]))
{
    $lon = $_POST["getlon"];
    echo 'Longitude : ', $lon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, separate the PHP processing. Now after getting the location using the callback then perform the AJAX. Sample Code:

`samepage3.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {

    $("#getlat").val(position.coords.latitude);
    $("#getlon").val(position.coords.longitude);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data:{
            getlat: $("#getlat").val(),
            getlon: $("#getlon").val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocation();
});
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="getlat" name="getlat" />
<input type="text" id="getlon" name="getlon" />
```

`request.php`

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $lat = $_POST["getlat"];
    $lon = $_POST["getlon"];
    echo json_encode(array('lat' => $lat, 'lon' => $lon));
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Just use a separate PHP page. This is a bad idea.

Comment: @PHPglue yes i know thats what i would suggest also to be honest, i just made it this way since i can't separate a php file for a demo anyway.

Comment: Ugh, `setTimeout` is a horrible, kludgey way to do it. Put that code in the callback function.

Comment: Why put everything on the same page?

Comment: @PrabowoMurti its separated now. okay?

Comment: @lock try out my revision

Comment: then what was on the console?

Comment: @HTTP was this addressed to me or the OP? before i posted this i made sure i got i working. and yes `console.log(response)` on my end a valid JSON response with two objects being `lat` and `lon`

Comment: @Ghost Im sorry that was for the OP

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is getLocation function will be a big delay, so you need to fire ajax call after getLocation is done. Please see the blow revised version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
    $.ajax({url:"samepage3.php",type:"POST",async:false,
           data:{getlat:$("#getlat").val(),getlon:$("#getlon").val()}
        });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">
<input type="text" id="getlat" name="getlat" /> 
<input type="text" id="getlon" name="getlon" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST["getlat"]))
{
    $lat = $_POST["getlat"];
    echo $lat;
}
if(isset($_POST["getlon"]))
{
    $lon = $_POST["getlon"];
    echo $lon;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The only change is doing ajax call in the function showPosition.

Comment: You cannot get the data in the first request, but you will get the data in the second request which is a ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The sole purpose of AJAX is to fetch and send data from a server without reloading the page.

You don't need any data from the server. You need data from the BROWSER--namely--geolocation coordinates, so AJAX and php have no bearing on what you need to do here. This can be done in pure HTML.

On the other hand, if you want to do something like save the coordinates to a database or use IP address as a fallback when the navigator doesn't support geolocation, that's when you could use the help of a server and AJAX would come into play.

Simply replace your ajax function with `getLocation()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        function getLocation() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
           }else{
             console.warn("Can't geolocate!");
             //this would be a good place to fall back on geolocation by IP (AJAX necessary)
           }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
          console.info('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude);
          document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
          console.info('Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude);
          document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            getLocation();
        });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <input type="text" id="getlat" name="getlat" /> 
     <input type="text" id="getlon" name="getlon" />
   </body>
</html>
```