# is it possible to convert AJAX response to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Or is it possible to convert JavaScript variable to php? I know that JavaScript is client side but still is it possible? If yes please tell me how.

Comment: It is but why would you do that? no point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing values from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539213/passing-values-from-javascript-to-php-using-ajax)

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: An AJAX response is usually generated on the server. Are you asking how to send what the server sent you back?

Answer (score 2):

The point of ajax is that you send your javascript variables to a php file(server file) where you can handle or save them. The response you get is an error message or the output generated by the php file so you don't need to save the response into a php variable.

Javascript var -> php var AJAX request
PHP var -> Javascript var AJAX respsonse

For a detailed explanation how ajax works please use google

Comment: is that really the **actual** use of ajax ? save them or handle them. AJAX responses are the backbone of ajax.

Comment: Yeah if you use ajax to exchange variables between the server and the client script. Of course you can use ajax for much more.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see that you accept that it's not a good habit to do that, so here's the answer.

If you want to transfer an `ajax response` to a php variable, there are 2 ways of doing the same.

## Method 1

The page to which an `AJAX` request is made, there ! The variable you use to send data back, assign it to a session variable using `$_SESSION` and then retrieve the data on another '`php` page' using the same session variable. But make sure that you wrap everything into an **`if`** block because you might land up in trouble if the ajax request failed (so nothing went to the session variable) and you use the session variable in some other page (*which isn't even assigned because the request failed*)

---

## Method 2

If you are using some third party API or you don't have access to the php server (*the source to which the `ajax` request was made*) then you can run an ajax request inside the success function (*assuming you are using JQUERY for the purpose. If you are not, wherever you get the response, assign it to another variable*) and then shoot an ajax request to your server and save the data into a variable using sessions as discussed in method 1.